# DJI Mobile SDK and DJI Simulator

Tags: dji-sdk

Is it possible with the Mobile SDK to write an application that receives way points from a web service and then starts the drone and monitors its operation?

The use case is as follows:
- Start drone
- Fly to a height of 2m
- Take picture/video and send/stream picture/video to the app
- Land again

Is it possible to simulate my code in the DJI Simulator and then when I know everything works use a Spark or Mavic for a real-life demonstration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes absolutely, although it's not necessarily MobileSDK specific and here's a example:

1/ You create a desktop (native or web) app that does the mission planning. This app can save the mission in a known format - My advice is to create a framework/library to manage this format -

2/ A mobile app built on top of the MobileSDK reads the mission in the format - using the said framework that manages this format.

3/ The mobile app translates the mission requirements into missions system available on MobileSDK either through WaypointMissions, MissionControl or even VirtualStick commands.

As for simulation, once the drone is in simulator mode, the execution will work and show how it executes.

If you want to take things further, you can even stream back from the mobile app data to your destkop app to superpose actual path against planned path.

I can't drop a code source for this as it's extensive, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: As I understood from DJI drones, they create a WiFi hotspot the mobile device is connecting to. So I would need a tablet with cellular or a laptop with a second internet connection to be able to connect to the web service and the drone at the same time, correct? Which simulation can I use with the Mobile SDK, is it the new DJI Simulator or DJI Assistant 2 or does it come with own simulator? How do they connect to each other? Do I need to have a drone connected (via USB) to actually run my code in the simulator or does this work without a drone?

Comment: Not necessarily, most of our drones actually connect the remote controller (or mobile device) using our proprietary tech (OcuSync). Some also offer wifi though but you'd want to leverage OcuSync for its performance. In this case, your mobile device connects to the remote controller using USB, leaving your wifi free to use.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now which connections are being used after reading up on OcuSync. Still not clear is where the simulator is being used. Lets say I develop an iOS app under Xcode on a Mac. How would I be able to simulate my code?

Comment: In this setup, you have two simulators in place: the iOS simulator, which runs on macOS, and the DJI simulator, which is a mode the aircraft goes into to execute commands without actually using the motors. Now in the Simulator tab of Assistant 2, you can visualize the DJI simulator data.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, Arnaud! So, a done is required in order to test the code. There is no pure software-in-the-loop approach possible as far as I understood.